# Any good graphical tree generators for android?

Tags: android, treeview

I am making an android app. I want to display a tree of images like this:

[image]

Except each node will have an ImageView and a TextView.

Is there any libraries I can use to do this, or how can I write code to do this?

Basically I can generate the tree data by making a class that has the views, and then it has a list of more of the class objects (i.e. its children), then I want to pass that object (root object) to some class and it will construct the tree thing which I can insert into the screen with java code.

I want to be able to zoom-in / out with pinching. And I want to be able to click on the images and detect the click events.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Hey,did you find any solution for it,then please post it as answer.

Comment: I did not find any solution yet...